# Kivy label opacity not being consistent

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning the basics of Kivy and going through tutorials. I noticed that when I start a Kivy app, the opacity of the labels are not consistent. Sometimes when I start the app, some labels are full opacity while others are half opacity.

[image: showing 3 half opacity buttons]

Sometimes I start the app and some labels are entirely opaque and missing.

[image: showing 3 fully opaque buttons]

I can't figure out why this is happening. All of the labels have the same definition and I believe should not be behaving this way.

I have tried just closing and starting the app over and over to see if there is a pattern and it seems that the first label in the top left is always consistent while the other 3 labels on the 3 other buttons are not.

I have also tried out some of the demo apps in kivy and the demo apps are showing this behavior as well.

Here are the files that I am using:

**test.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class GridLayoutApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return GridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glApp = GridLayoutApp()
    glApp.run()
```

**gridlayout.kv**

```
<GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10

    Button:
        text: "1st"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    Button:
        text: "2nd"
    Button:
        text: "3rd"
        size_hint_x: None
        width: 200
    Button:
        text: "4th"
```

I expected all of the buttons to have the same opacity. Sometimes the program does get this right but most of the time, the opacity is off for some reason.

I have no idea how to even approach this problem so any suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug that appeared during an sdl2 version update. It's fixed in Kivy 1.11, released a couple of days ago, make sure your Kivy is up to date.

Comment: Ah okay. I was on Kivy 1.10 and upgrading to 1.11 fixed the problem immediately. Thank you very much for the quick reply